# Sorting an array of array by a certain value in the inner array

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
test = [["E","188","12314","87235"],["B","1803","12314","87235"],["C","1508","12314","87235"]]
```

I want to sort the whole array by the second value in the inner arrays (188,1803,1508). So this is what I want to have.

```
test = [["E","188","12314","87235"],["C","1508","12314","87235"],["B","1803","12314","87235"]]
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? Do I need to write a `sort` to do it?

Comment: The logic is not clear. If you sort them, the order should be `"1508"`, `"1803"`, `"188"`.

Comment: What do you mean by the order should be "1508", "1803", "188"? I want them to be in ascending order.

Comment: Yes. ascending order. Just try it. `["188", "1803", "1508"].sort # => ["1508", "1803", "188"]`.

Comment: That's because the elements are strings, not integers.

Comment: Jack, @sawa is making the point that if you want the arrays sorted by the second elements after they are converted to integers, you've got to say that. You may think it's obvious, but it's not. Programming is all about precision, with your description of what you want to do or have done, as well as the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with `sort_by`:

```
test.sort_by { |e| e[1].to_i }
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Go with @Maxim's answer, but you could also write:

```
test.sort { |e,f| e[1].to_i <=> f[1].to_i }
  #=> [["E",  "188", "12314", "87235"],
  #    ["C", "1508", "12314", "87235"],
  #    ["B", "1803", "12314", "87235"]]
```